# Calling a private function using a public funtion

Tags: c++

In my assignment, i am required to call a private function (simplify) from a public function ( set(int,int) ). When i try to compile, i get an error that says redefinition of set . Im not sure what im doing wrong, or what the error means. any help is very much appreciated. Here is what i have:

```
//Fraction.h

struct Fraction{
    private:
            int numerator;
            int denonminator;
            void simplify();

    public:
            void set(int n, int d){void simplify();};
            void display() const;
};

//Fraction.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"

void Fraction::set(int n, int d){
    numerator = n;
    denonminator = d;
    simplify();
}

void Fraction::simplify(){
    int i;
    for (i = denonminator * numerator;  i > 1; i--){
            if( denonminator % i == 0 && numerator % i == 0){
                    numerator = numerator/i;
                    denonminator = denonminator/i;
                }
        }
}

void Fraction::display () const{
        cout << numerator << " / " << denonminator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are  defining set twice.. Better declare it once

```
struct Fraction{
    private:
            int numerator;
            int denonminator;
            void simplify();

    public:
           // Dont use this-- void set(int n, int d){void simplify();}; //Defined here once
            void set(int n, int d); //Just declare it
            void display() const;
};

//Fraction.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Fraction.h"

void Fraction::set(int n, int d){//Defined it again
    numerator = n;
    denonminator = d;
    simplify();
}

void Fraction::simplify(){
    int i;
    for (i = denonminator * numerator;  i > 1; i--){
            if( denonminator % i == 0 && numerator % i == 0){
                    numerator = numerator/i;
                    denonminator = denonminator/i;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fraction::set` is implemented twice: You already implemented it in the header - and implement it again in the .cpp file.

You have to decide on one implementation.

Looking at what both implementations do, you should probably change the header to read

```
//...
void set(int n, int d);
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined `set` twice:

```
struct Fraction{
    void set(int n, int d){void simplify();}; // <== #1
};
```

And:

```
void Fraction::set(int n, int d) { // <== #2
    numerator = n;
    denonminator = d;
    simplify();
}
```

The first definition doesn't do what you want anyway - it's not calling `simplify`, it's declaring a local function named `simplify` that takes no arguments and returns `void` - which has nothing to do with `Fraction::simplify`. So just replace it with:

```
void set(int n, int d);
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that the first definition is invalid? It looks to [contain a perfectly valid function declaration](https://ideone.com/yrOqZs) to me...

Comment: @gha.st I mean invalid in the sense of what OP wanted to do - I clarified.

Comment: i did define it twice, it makes sense now. thanks a lot